# Is there a way to delete / disable Action plan from Communities template

Tags: community, standard-objects, digital-experience, financial-services-cloud

Seems like Action plan is default to the communities, and I am unable to install the package in sandbox which is not (Financial service cloud enterprise), which means that org does not have 'Action plan object'. Now my communities is not using the 'Action plan' anywhere, hence was wondering if there is a way out to remove/disable it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete the Action Plan(Given extended permission "Delete") but not the Action Plan Template. It is designed to not be deleted because that would cause problems for any existing action plans that used the template.  Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fsc_action_plans_create_templates.htm&type=5).

Thanks